# Encountered two children with the same key(Jest)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

Hi I was doing unit testing for react components , every time the uniqid will be generated so i am using jest.mock('uniqid', () => i => `${i}someUniqId`); , It sets key for both parent and client components it seems

> jest.mock('uniqid', () => i => `${i}someUniqId`);

But it throws a **Warning**

[image]

How to solve this issue ,  is this right approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Best way to solve this issue ,

Steps

1. Use redux devtools
2. get rawdata ,
3. Use middlewares send mock data as a store
4. Use Thunk to middle ware if you pass action as a parameter